# flatten API response, and renaming prop - is there a solution by iterating key/value pair?

Tags: javascript, typescript, iteration

I want to sum up and flatten the structure of an API response. Since I didn't succeed by iterating over the key/value pairs of input.statistic I came up with another solution which does the job but I'm not happy with it.

What I do recieve is:

```
input = {
"data": some unimportant stuff,
"statistic": [
    {
      "valueId": 111,
      "statistic": {
        "min": 0,
        "max": 0,
        "average": 0.12
      }
    },
    {
      "valueId": 222,
      "statistic": {
        "min": 0,
        "max": 1,
        "average": 0.14
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

At this point I'm only interested in the statistic data and I want to change it to something like that:

```
{
"stat111": [
   {name: "min", value: 0},
   {name: "max", value: 0},
   {name: "average", value: 0.12}
  ],
"stat222": [
   {name: "min", value: 0},
   {name: "max", value: 1},
   {name: "average", value: 0.14}
  ]
}
```

What I do is:

```
const statDat = {};
for (const item of input.statistic) {
  const nameTop = 'stat' + item.valueId.toString();
  const props = [];
    for (let key in item.statistic) {
      props.push({name: key, value: item.statistic[key]});
    }
  statDat[nameTop] = props;
}
```

So statDat looks the way I want it but once more I'm sure that there is a better and newer way of flatten and renaming the structure. Any hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking for "newer", then I would recommend familiarizing yourself with a good Javascript api, such as [the Mozilla Developer Network's](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript).  That has such entries as [array's forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), [destructuring assignments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), and [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).  Those (and [the new object notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#new_notations_in_ecmascript_2015)) combine to change your code to

```js
const statDat = {};
input.statistic.forEach( (item) => {
    const nameTop = 'stat' + item.valueId; // toString() unnecessary
    statDat[nameTop] = Object.entries(item.statistic).map( ([name,value]) => ({name,value}) );
});
```

we can also use [Object.fromEntries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) as in Jonah's answer to get these five lines down to one command (which I break into 4 lines for readability).

```js
const statDat2 = Object.fromEntries( input.statistic.map( ({valueId,statistic}) => [
    'stat'+valueId,
    Object.entries(statistic).map( ([name,value]) => ({name,value}) )
] ) );
```

```js
const input = {
"data": "some unimportant stuff",
"statistic": [
    {
      "valueId": 111,
      "statistic": {
        "min": 0,
        "max": 0,
        "average": 0.12
      }
    },
    {
      "valueId": 222,
      "statistic": {
        "min": 0,
        "max": 1,
        "average": 0.14
      }
    }
  ]
};
const statDat = {};
input.statistic.forEach( (item) => {
    const nameTop = 'stat' + item.valueId;
    statDat[nameTop] = Object.entries(item.statistic).map( ([name,value]) => ({name,value}) );
});
console.log(statDat);
// or
const statDat2 = Object.fromEntries( input.statistic.map( ({valueId,statistic}) => [
    'stat'+valueId,
    Object.entries(statistic).map( ([name,value]) => ({name,value}) )
] ) );
console.log(statDat2);
```

Compressing five lines of code into one usually makes that one line a bit harder to understand than any of the five original lines, but much easier to understand overall.

Comment: I do agree with you that a one liner makes it harder to understand - although Jonahs answer works very well, too. Thxs!

Comment: TBH, I like the Object.fromEntries approach.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, your data transformation is just a map, and we want the code to reflect that.  Here's a one liner with no mutation or intermediate variables:

```
Object.fromEntries(input.statistic.map(x => [`stat${x.valueId}`, x.statistic]))
```

Comment: Thxs for your solution. It works very well, too.

Comment: (Although you need to work with `x.statistic` to match OP's output.)